# How to create and navigate between same webpage's segments

Tags: html, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

[image: segments]

I am looking for the best way to create and navigate/redirect between page segments like the one in the red circle (idk if they are called segments).

I am using React and Redux. Is react-router a good idea?

Do you guys know of a good learning guide for create and navigate between segments of the same page?

Answer (score 1):

React router is almost definitely what you are looking for, it provides all the functionality required for rendering different views / elements based on URL path. As well as navigating between 'pages' (without reloading the page)

This provides a really good intro:
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/guides/philosophy